# Solaris VNC Autostart with pseudocolors

Tags: solaris, vnc, solaris-10, vnc-server

i followed the oracle guidelines to start vnc server at boot using

```
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server add display1
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server:display1 addpg options application
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server:display1 addpropvalue options/server astring: "/usr/X11/bin/Xvnc"
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server:display1 addpropvalue options/server_args astring: '"SecurityTypes=None"'
 mkdir -p /etc/dt/config
cp /usr/dt/config/Xservers /etc/dt/config/Xservers
echo "   :1   Local local_uid@none root /usr/X11/bin/Xserver :1" >> /etc/dt/config/Xservers
pkill -HUP dtlogin
```

and that works just fine. My problem is that i need a very specific Xvnc with parameters "-cc3 -depth 8". So i added them with

```
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server:display1 addpropvalue options/server_args astring: '"-cc 3"'
svccfg -s application/x11/x11-server:display1 addpropvalue options/server_args astring: '"-depth 8"'
```

listprop in svccfg looks okay but the server does not start after `pkill -HUP dtlogin` and also not after a reboot. Also tried to put all params into a single string.
`setpprop options/server_args "SecurityTypes=None -cc 3 -depth 8"`

Before adding cc and depth, when the vnc was running, `ps -ef | grep vnc` revealed, that `-depth 24` was automatically added to the command line. So i also tried only the cc option - no success. I also can not see which logs might contain relevant information.

Has anyone successfully startet an VNC with pseudocolors at boot time?

(The inetd way works with pseudocolors, but in the end i need 2 fixed vnc servers running on display :1(pseudocolor) and :2(FullColor)

Answer (score 1):

The Xserver script automatically sets `-depth 24` - to change this you need to change the `options/default_depth` property on the x11-server service - in Solaris 10, see the Xserver man page for details.